# Trim string starting at comma - Excel

Tags: excel

I have an csv sheet with data of Employee as Last Name, First Name.
Below is an example. (These values are in a single cell)

```
Flynn, Jeremy  
Early, Allison   
Epstein, David   
Newman, Joanna  
Biord, Brooke
```

I need to left trim the data so that I only need the first name without any trailing space or comma.

OutPut Sample should be:

```
Jeremy 
Allison 
David 
Joanna 
Brooke
```

How can I write a formula or macro that will process the entire sheet of more that 5000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a formula in an used column to the right using the [REPLACE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Replace-Function-6ACF209B-01B7-4078-B4B8-E0A4EF67D181),

```
=REPLACE(A1, IFERROR(FIND(",", A1), LEN(A1)), LEN(A1), TEXT(,))
```

As a VBA sub procedure using [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx),

```
Sub firstOnly_bySel()
    With Selection
        .Replace what:=",*", replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlPart
        'selection.replace(
    End With
End Sub
```

Select one or more cells and run the sub from the Macros dialog ([alt]+[F8])

Answer (score 1):

Formula, in an empty column put:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,Find(",",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
```

Where A1 is the first cell of your list.  Then copy down the entire list.

If you want vba this will do it nearly instantly:

```
Sub firstName()
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        'Change the Second Criterion in Each .Cells() to the column number of your data.
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        'Change the Offset value to the number of columns to offset the answer.
        rng.Offset(, 1).Value = .Evaluate("Index(TRIM(MID(" & rng.Address & ",Find("",""," & rng.Address & ")+1,LEN(" & rng.Address & "))),)")
    End With
End Sub
```

It assumes you data is in column A and it will put it in column B

Answer (score 0):

Just do simple find and replace. Find ",*" and Leave Replace blank.